# SharePoint Workflow Task Escalation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Does anyone know if when you use the action to escalate a task after it's expired if it completes the task for the person who let it expire? I'm not finding much out there about this. I do have a test going to reproduce the issue and see what happens but I have to wait for the task to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I have finalized my testing and it does appear that once a workflow escalates a task it will mark the overdue task as complete.